# Will ICE negotiations between peers behind two symmetric NAT's result in requiring two TURN servers?

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, ice

I read [RFC6577](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766) and [RFC8445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8445) but I feel like there is a bit of a disconnect between how TURN ***can*** be used versus how ICE ***actually*** utilizes the `relay candidates`.

The TURN RFC describes the use of one single TURN server to ferry data between a client and a peer. The `transport address` on the TURN server accepts data flow from a client via TURN messages, whereas the `relayed transport address` accepts data flow from peer(s) via UDP. This sounds great - one TURN server and bidirectional data flow.

However in reading about ICE, I feel like this never happens. Both caller and callee independently allocate on potentially two TURN servers, and then send their respective `relayed transport addresses` to each other. More like an `I can be reached via this relayed transport address` sort of thing. Connectivity checks then occur and thus, two TURN servers end up being used here where data only flows in one direction through the `relayed transport address` of each participants allocated TURN server.

Is this true?

From the TURN RFC, it says the following:

> The client can arrange for the server to relay packets to and from
> certain other hosts (called peers) and can control aspects of how the
> relaying is done. The client does this by obtaining an IP address and
> port on the server, called the relayed transport address. When a peer
> sends a packet to the relayed transport address, the server relays the
> packet to the client.  When the client sends a data packet to the
> server, the server relays it to the appropriate peer using the relayed
> transport address as the source.

However, I can't see a scenario whereby through ICE negotiations, data would ever flow through the transport address from the client to the peer. Both the caller and the callee independently allocate on a TURN server and send `relayed transport addresses` to each other to be reached on.

Basically, TURN ***can*** do bidirectional data flow, but with ICE between two symmetric NAT's, it ***wont***. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a bit complicated.... bear with me. Reading just the TURN RFC isn't enough, you need context from [RFC 5245](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245) on ICE too.

The following scenario is the baseline case:

1. client A allocates a relay address 8.8.8.8:43739, sends it to client B
2. client B sends a UDP packet to 8.8.8.8:43739
3. TURN servers wraps the packet in a stun message, sends it to client A

Now as you say, typically client B will also allocate its own relay address and send it to A. Why isn't that used all the time (or half the time)? The priorities of the candidates are equal after all.
However the [candidate pair priority](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245#section-5.7.2) which determines which pair to pick includes a factor which acts as a tie-breaker:

```
      pair priority = 2^32*MIN(G,D) + 2*MAX(G,D) + (G>D?1:0)
Where G>D?1:0 is an expression whose value is 1 if G is greater than
D, and 0 otherwise.
```

This means the pair where the callers (assuming its the controlling agent) relay address is used has a higher priority than the pair with the callees relay address.

Additionally, there is another candidate in the game here for the port client B uses to send to port 8.8.8.8:43739. This will typically be from one of the local candidates and the TURN server sees (and puts into the data indication) the public (post-nat) ip of client B. On client A this will show up as a remote srflx candidate -- which has a higher priority than a relayed candidate and will therefore be used.

Now if B is behind a symmetric NAT (I *think*) the TURN server will see a different port from client B than anything for which client A has added a permission. This will typically mean the TURN server will drop the packet and that pair won't work.

If client A is not behind a symmetric NAT, the baseline process will be repeated in the other direction. Slightly less priority but its the same in terms of latency so users won't notice.

If both clients are (and now we are finally at the case you're asking about) are behind symmetric NAT, neither will work and a relay-relay pair will be used. This is fairly rare (<1% probably) and the latency impact is typically insignificant even when both clients are on different TURN servers.

Comment: That is extremely interesting. That means that if the SRFX candidate can be used on one participant, the single required TURN will only ever have unidirectional media flow. And if both are behind bad NAT's, then they will both use different TURN servers respectively. Does that mean that TURN server's in use with WebRTC/ICE are never bidirectional?

Comment: they definetly are bidirectional. Only pairs with bidirectional connectivity are considered even

Comment: Well, for the majority of TURN use cases, you said that the pairing is typically `Bad NAT <-> Good NAT` with over 99% of calls. That means that TURN messages will never be used to send data from the controlling agent to the controlled agent, since the controlling agent will merely use the SRFX addr of the controlled. That's what I meant. The TURN server in the majority of cases will only ever receive data on the relayed transport address, but never on the transport address in the opposite direction since it doesn't have to.

Comment: In the scenario you described above with two symmetric NATs... do they use the same relay or two differently allocated relays? For example, will client A and client B have their own allocated (separate) relays in which they can be reached at?

Comment: that depends on the setup. Different relay servers might be used, TURN doesn't care that the other end is a TURN server.